# Redux updating/fetch communication - bug infinite loop in process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a react/redux site - I have basic experience with redux. I have a call that will assess an "alert" count -- and I have a form that pushes data to a server.

If the user has yet to fill in the form - the alert count is 1, once they have filled in the form the alert count is set to 0. I need to get communication and lookups happening though when the user has filled in the form --- but what I've done although updates the redux - starts to go through an infinite loop.

I know there is a "componentWillReceiveProps" - but it seems unreachable in my codebase once the user has submitted the form.. I did an if check in the render and this is where the infinite loop occurs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchAddSDQ } from '../../actions/addSDQAction';
import { fetchAlerts } from '../../actions/alertAction';

import { Row, Col } from 'antd';

// components
import AddSDQSyncValidationForm from './AddSDQSyncValidationForm'


// this is a class because it needs state
class AddSDQ extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    // console.log('this', this)
  }

  submit(data) {
    console.log("submitting AddSDQ");
    this.props.fetchAddSDQ(data);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(){

  }


  render() {

    if(this.props.addSDQData.data){
        //update the alerts.
        //this.props.fetchAlerts(null);

        //return false;
    }


    return (
      <div className="Page">

            <div className="form-components light">
                <Row>
                  <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={10}>
                    <p>Add SQL</p>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24}>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24}>
                        <AddSDQSyncValidationForm onSubmit={this.submit} />
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>

      </div>
    )
  }

}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    addSDQData: state.addSDQ,
    alertData: state.alert
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({ fetchAddSDQ, fetchAlerts }, dispatch);
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddSDQ))
//export default AddSDQ
```

Comment: So basically your component keeps trying to re-render? (as the loop happens on the render) Try console.log this.props where you enter the loop, and see if props are changing

Comment: well - its where the prop gets satisfied -- its not that the components tries to keep re-rendering -- but it keeps calling the fetchAlerts -- because the user has submitted the form -- its response is now true -- fetch alert --- repeat, repeat, repeat ...

Comment: Oh, I understand now. You get on a loop there when that code is not commented

Answer (score 0):

Using componentWillReceiveProps like this should work:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  if(newProps.addSDQData.data && !this.props.addSDQData.data){
      //update the alerts.
      this.props.fetchAlerts(null);
  }
}
```

This code makes it so that fetchAlerts is only called once, when addSDQdata.data becomes a truthy value

Also, you shouldn't do things that change the state of the redux inside the render method, you should use React lifecycle methods

But if you want to do that inside the render, you could send an action that changes addSDQData.data to a falsy value before you fetchAlerts